# Trap command is not triggering in /bin/sh script

Tags: c++, linux, bash, signals

I have a /bin/sh script with trap command like below.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Define signal handler function
sigint_handler() {
    echo "Received SIGTERM signal."
    exit 1
}

# Set up signal handler
trap sigint_handler TERM

# Wait for a signal
echo "Waiting for signal..."
while [ 1 ]
do
sleep 4m&
p="$!"
wait
unset p

done
```

If I run that script standalone it is working as expected.
if i kill with kill -15 pid
Getting print "Received SIGTERM signal."
If I start same script from c++ program using execvp,the script is started but the trap is not triggering
Below is the c++ function  which spawns the process and returns the pids and waitpid status(ws) to the caller.
Note :- this function is called from multiple threads.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>      /* for 'printf' and 'NULL' */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for 'errno' */
#include <errno.h>

pid_t fork_process (pid_t &new_pid,string process_start(here test.sh)){
    int ws;
    int status;

    printf("Parent: %d\n", getpid());
char *args[]={"./test.sh",NULL}
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0){
        printf("Child %d\n", getpid());
    int r=execvp(args[0],args);
 if (r < 0) {

        const int err = errno;

      printf( "exec failed with errno: %d", err);
      exit(err);
    }
    }
     new_pid=pid;
     ws=waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);
    printf("%d\n",ws);
    return ws;
}
```

any suggestions ?

Started /bin/sh script with execvp from c/c++ code ,trap is not getting triggerd in script

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. How exactly do you send the signal to the shell process started from the C program? How do you detect that the `trap` function is not executed? Why do you run `sleep` in the background?

Comment: The (very C-like) C++ code is working on my machine, and the trap is getting triggered.

Comment: Are you sending SIGTERM to the parent process or the child process?

Comment: @chepner to the child process(test.sh)

Comment: Are you sure? Your C++ code doesn't make much sense: if `sleep(2); exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` actually execute, the `execvp` did *not* succeed, so it doesn't seem to make sense to use `EXIT_SUCCESS` as your exit status. Are you sure the `execvp` actually worked? Is `./test.sh` actually executable?

Comment: @Bodo kill -15 pid(childpid),

Comment: @Eljay updated the code, fork_process is called from multiple threads to spawn a process.

Comment: **Please [edit] your question to add requested information.** Don't use comments for this purpose. It is not clear what `kill -15 pid(childpid)` means. Describe in detail how you get the PID. Do you use the shell's `kill` command? How did you check that the shell process is still running when you want to send the signal. Your code is incomplete and contains syntax errors. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: What I understand (after your edit) is, that you start the script from C ... not the C program from the script, right?

So the script gets the SIGTERM and correctly catches it with your sigint_handler(). This causes the script to terminate, leaving nothing more then a return code to the calling C program and its waitpid() call. Alas, the C code misses its end, where the handling of received status information should be located ... please add that part. And the main function (that was contained earlier) seems to be gone now :-)

Comment: Thanks @Synopsis,updated the code,fork_process function is called from multiple threads to spawn the process.

Answer (score 2):

The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image, so by calling execvp() the rest of your C code is not existing anymore.

Use one of spawn() family to launch a CHILD process.

Comment: The `fork` spawns a child process, the `execvp` is replacing that child process.

Comment: tried using posix_spawn(),still facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue parent process was blocking the signals ,same got inherited for child process also.We can unblock the signals like this /usr/bin/env --default-signal=TERM ./test.sh